# Angular Material Data Table - Can't Sort

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

Trying to sort my data and for some reason it's not working. All examples use a local array of values, while mine is an API call which returns an array of objects, of which, each item has a 'name' property.

I can load the page and see the sort header arrow but clicking doesn't produce a change. I'm using a function call to get my 'clients' and calling that in the constructor, but it's failed for me in both OnInit as well. I have also checked that my column def is identical to my data field returned, namely 'name' but that's not helping either.

------ TS ---------

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { ClientService } from "../../../core/services/client.service";
import { Client } from "../../../core/models/client.interface";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { ClientDialogComponent } from "../client-dialog/client-dialog.component";
import { ConfirmDeleteDialogComponent } from "../../../core/components/confirm-delete-dialog/confirm-delete-dialog.component";
import { SnackbarService } from "src/app/core/services/snackbar.service";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material/table";
import { MatSort } from "@angular/material/sort";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "./clients.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./clients.component.css"],
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Client[]>;
  client: Client;
  tableColumns: string[] = ["name", "website", "phone", "actions"];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(
    private _clientService: ClientService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _snackbar: SnackbarService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.getClients();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  getClients() {
    // Get clients from API
    this._clientService.getClients().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);   <----- this is simple array of objects
      },
      (error) => {
        this._snackbar.show(error["message"], "warn-snackbar");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

-------- HTML --------------

```html
<div *ngIf="dataSource; else spinner">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="search">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Filter" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-button">
      <button *hasClaim="'canAddClient'" type="button" mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="add-client-button"
        (click)="addClientDialog()">
        Add Client
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-table">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <!-- row / column definitions -->
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns" [ngClass]="'table-header'"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns">
        </tr>
        <!-- client -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Client</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client"> {{client.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- website -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="website">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Website</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client"> {{client.website}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- phone -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Phone</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client"> {{client.phone | formatPhone}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- actions -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client">
            <button mat-stroked-button class="action-button" color="primary" (click)="goToDetailsPage(client._id)">
              Info
            </button>
            <button *hasClaim="'canEditClient'" mat-stroked-button class="action-button" color="primary"
              (click)="editClientDialog(client)">
              Edit
            </button>
            <button *hasClaim="'canDeleteClient'" mat-stroked-button class="action-button" color="warn"
              (click)="deleteClientDialog(client)">
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #spinner>
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is happening because you are setting the sort on the `dataSource` before the `ViewChild` is defined.  There are two ways that should fix this:

1. Add `{static: true}` to your `@ViewChild` definition as below:

   ```js
   @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
   ```

   This causes the Angular to eagerly fetch the `MatSort` element, so it is available in `ngOnInit`.
2. Move the sort assignment into `ngAfterViewInit`.  In the code you provided, you can rename the `ngOnInit` function to `ngAfterViewInit`.  This works because non-static `ViewChild` objects are available in `ngAfterViewInit`.

If you're interested, you can read up on the [difference between `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) and the `static` flag to [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

Comment: That was it. Moved to after view init. Would I also need to add static as well

Comment: Either approach works, but you don't need to do both.  `ViewChild`s not marked static are not defined in `ngOnInit`, so you need to use a later lifecycle hook or mark it as static.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your table from CLI ? It packs a lot of functionality by default and saves a lot of time as well.

There you can hit your API and store the data, pretty straight forward process. For your current table, I don't know why it's not working properly

Comment: Thanks, thats a good point. I'm trying to go through myself in the beginning to learn it, then I'll take your suggestion, might be easier

Comment: this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; this line should be after this.dataSource